# How to compile specific module of the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

So I simply cloned the Linux kernel (git clone) and executed:
`make`
and
`make modules` in the root directory. I then made my changes to a file in the drivers/staging/android folder and wanted to compile the module.
To compile the module I executed:
`make M=drivers/staging/android`
But the output was simply a `MODPOST: *` message. If I execute the command again now, it outputs nothing. I deliberately added errors to a .c file, saved the file and the output of the make command was still nothing.
So my question is how do I compile a single module in the Linux kernel?

Comment: *"So I simply cloned the linux kernel (git clone) and executed: `make` ..."* -- Didn't  you configure the kernel before building it?  That is expected per Linux kernel documentation.  Study **Documentation/admin-guide/README.rst**.      *"how do I compile a single module in the linux kernel?"* -- According to `make help`, use `make dir/file.ko`

Comment: I forgot to include that, I did configure the kernel. Regarding your comment I did not found a .ko file in any of the directories (drivers/*).